# How to restrict a user to use only one plugin in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, restriction, wordpress-admin

I want to restrict a specific user to use only one plugin. I don't want him to see any other pages on the WordPress admin dashboard like the Plugins page, Posts, or other pages. I want to show him just one link in the admin dashboard and let him to use just that page.

I want to do it programmatically and don't want to use a plugin for it.

I implemented the same functionality to restrict users by the code below but I want to know is there any better solution for it or not. It redirect user to '/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product' if he doesn't visit the valid pages that I declared in $pages array.
I'm using WooCommerce, the post_type=product is for that.

Could you help me to achieve this, please? Thank you.

The code I wrote in functions.php file before to achieve this, the issue if I have to set all pages and plugins ID manually:

```
add_action('current_screen', 'checkUserPermissionsInThisScreen');

function checkUserPermissionsInThisScreen(){

    if (is_admin()){

      $a = get_current_screen();
      $currentUserName = wp_get_current_user()->user_login;

      if ($currentUserName === "testuser") {

         $pages = array(
          'dashboard',
          'toplevel_page_wpcf7',
          'contact_page_wpcf7-new',
          'contact_page_wpcf7-integration',
          'edit-shop_order',
          'edit-shop_coupon',
          'woocommerce_page_dgwt_wcas_settings',
          'woocommerce_page_wc-reports',
          'woocommerce_page_wc-settings',
          'woocommerce_page_wc-status',
          'woocommerce_page_wc-addons', 
          'woocommerce_page_alg-wc-renumerate-orders-tools',
          'themes',
          'customize',
          'users',
          'tools',
          'import',
          'export',
          'site-health',
          'export-personal-data',
          'erase-personal-data',
          'tools_page_action-scheduler',
          'options-general',
          'options-writing',
          'options-reading',
          'options-discussion',
          'options-media',
          'options-permalink',
          'options-privacy',
          'toplevel_page_agilewc',
          'toplevel_page_smush',
          'shop_order'
        );


        remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' ); 
        remove_menu_page( 'woocommerce' );
        remove_menu_page( 'wpcf7' );
        remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );
        remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
        remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );
        remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );
        remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );
        remove_menu_page( 'smush' );

        //Remove the "WooCommerce Recent Reviews" widget.
        remove_meta_box('woocommerce_dashboard_recent_reviews', 'dashboard', 'normal');
        //Remove the "WooCommerce Status" widget.
        remove_meta_box('woocommerce_dashboard_status', 'dashboard', 'normal');
        //Hide the "Coupon data" meta box.
        remove_meta_box('woocommerce-coupon-data', $a->id, 'normal');
        //Hide the "Order data" meta box.
        remove_meta_box('woocommerce-order-data', $a->id, 'normal');
        //Hide the "Items" meta box.
        remove_meta_box('woocommerce-order-items', $a->id, 'normal');
        //Hide the "Downloadable product permissions" meta box.
        remove_meta_box('woocommerce-order-downloads', $a->id, 'normal');
        //Hide the "Order actions" meta box.
        remove_meta_box('woocommerce-order-actions', $a->id, 'side');
        //Hide the "Order notes" meta box.
        remove_meta_box('woocommerce-order-notes', $a->id, 'side');

      } 

        global $pagenow;

        if ( ( ! in_array($a->id, $pages) || $pagenow === 'post-new.php' ) ) {
          wp_redirect(get_site_url() . "/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product");
          die;
        } 
        
      }


    }
}
```

Comment: _"but I want to know is there any better solution for it or not."_ - If the code works but you just want to know if it's OK or if it can be improved, you should probably post it in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you for mentioning that, the code works but it's my solution and I'm pretty sure it's not the way to implement this but thank you so much to mentioning that,